# How to pass array data inside ViewController to UICollectionView Custom Cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am making a tableView inside custom 'UICollectionViewCell' and inside my ViewController I have an array containing data to be displayed in TableView at each row. 
Therefore, I want to pass the data of this array to custom cell (containing tableview delegates methods).

**I am doing like this but its not helping.**

**Inside "GroupCollectionViewCell.m"**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *groupTableIdentifier = @"DeptGroupTable";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:groupTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

    }
    RoadmapViewController *vc = [[RoadmapViewController alloc] init];
    cell.textLabel.text =[vc.grouplist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

**And inside "RoadViewController.m"**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    GroupCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[GroupCollectionViewCell alloc] init];
        // [cell.groupData addObjectsFromArray:_grouplist];
        //:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

**Note** - groupList if the array which I want to pass and groupData is a blank array inside custom cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one `MutableArray` object inside your `CollectionViewCell` and one method like this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrObj;

-(void)loadTableData(NSMutableArray*)arr {
     self.arrObj = arr;
     [self.tableView reloadData];
     //Now used this arrObj in your delegate and datasource method
}
```

After that call this function from `cellForItemAtIndexPath` like this way

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

{
    GroupCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[GroupCollectionViewCell alloc] init];
        // [cell.groupData addObjectsFromArray:_grouplist];
        //:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    [cell loadTableData:arr];
    return cell;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Everything is fine but I don't know why I am not able to get "loadTableData" method from "cell".

Comment: Sorry i forgot you need to declare this method in `CollectionViewCell.h` file. Declare that method and it will be available to you.

Comment: I have already declared. I think cell.loadTableData(arr) will not work. I need to use in other way.

Comment: you need to write like this `[cell loadTableData:arr];` i have write it in swift. I have edited my answer check that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `alloc init` to create `RoadmapViewController` and get `grouplist` from that, it is obviously that your `vc.grouplist` will return `nil`.

Remove these two lines:

```
RoadmapViewController *vc = [[RoadmapViewController alloc] init];
cell.textLabel.text =[vc.grouplist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

And do this:

```
cell.textLabel.text =[_groupData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

And in "`RoadViewController.m`" add this method:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(GroupCollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{        
    cell.groupData = _groupList;
    [collectionView reloadData];
}
```